# SQLite Join Help

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

Consider this table structure

```
people{id,firstName,lastName,preferredName}
list{id,person1_id,person2_id}
```

I want to get all data from list but with the names of the persons instead of IDs and with a twist: if `preferredName` is set, use that, otherwise use `firstName+SPACE+lastName`.

The query if I only needed one name would be this:

```
SELECT list.id,
CASE WHEN people.preferredName IS NULL OR people.preferredName="" THEN people.firstName||' '||people.lastName ELSE people.preferredName END AS preferredName 
FROM list LEFT JOIN people ON list.person1_id=people.id;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COALESCE() returns its first non-null argument.

```
COALESCE(preferredName, firstName || ' ' || lastName) as person_name
```

I don't think you need left joins, but I could be wrong. (If you have a foreign key constraint such that person1_id and person2_id must exist in people, you don't need a left join.)

```
SELECT list.id,
COALESCE( p1.preferredName, p1.firstName || ' ' || p1.lastName) as person1_name,
COALESCE( p2.preferredName, p2.firstName || ' ' || p2.lastName) as person2_name,
FROM list 
INNER JOIN people p1 ON list.person1_id= p1.id
INNER JOIN people p2 on list.person2_id = p2.id
```

Comment: Thanks, that's easier to write than the case statement, but it won't work for two columns, same error: "ambiguous column preferredName".

Comment: "Ambiguous column" means you need to prepend either the table name or its alias. (With multiple joins, usually the alias.) So p1.preferredName for the column derived from the join aliased p1, or p2.preferredName for the column derived from the join aliased p2.

Comment: I know the reason for the error, didn't think to alias the table names. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use table aliases to let you join the same table twice.

```
SELECT list.id,
       CASE WHEN people1.preferredName IS NULL OR people1.preferredName = ""
         THEN people1.firstName || ' ' || people1.lastName
         ELSE people1.preferredName
       END AS preferredName1,
       CASE WHEN people2.preferredName IS NULL OR people2.preferredName = ""
         THEN people2.firstName || ' ' || people2.lastName
         ELSE people2.preferredName
       END AS preferredName2,
  FROM list
  LEFT JOIN people people1 ON list.person1_id = people1.id
  LEFT JOIN people people2 ON list.person2_id = people2.id
```

Comment: Thank you as well, Neil. I chose the other answer by timing.

Comment: @Francisc Catcall's answer isn't what I saw when I originally read the question, otherwise I wouldn't have bothered; I guess he must have edited it while I was entering my answer.